# How do I set locale on Mac OS X platforms?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, azure-devops-server-2019, xcode11.3

I'm using Azure-DevOps Server pipeline to compile an IOS application with an IOS agent (macOS Big Sur) while using Xcpretty for tests and code coverage reports.
The Xcpretty not working:

> /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/lib/xcpretty/parser.rb:434:in `===': invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII (ArgumentError) from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/lib/xcpretty/parser.rb:434:in` update_test_state'
> from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/lib/xcpretty/parser.rb:307:in `parse' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/lib/xcpretty/formatters/formatter.rb:88:in` pretty_format'
> from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/lib/xcpretty/printer.rb:19:in `pretty_print' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/bin/xcpretty:84:in` block in <top (required)>'
> from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/bin/xcpretty:83:in `each_line' from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/xcpretty-0.3.0/bin/xcpretty:83:in` <top (required)>'
> from /usr/local/bin/xcpretty:23:in `load' from /usr/local/bin/xcpretty:23:in` '

Everybody on google says that all I've got to do is to change my locale with the bash command:

> export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
>
> export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

and it not working, I think that the problem is that this export is per terminal and not global, if I put this command on bash and print "locale" I got:
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcxY2.png)

If I use the export commands: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwDwX.png)

And after opening a new terminal:
[Again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYEJl.png)

Any idea to change it globally?

Comment: To narrow down if this issue is related to  Azure-DevOps Server pipeline side or your agent environment. What's the result if you directly build/compile your application on your local agent？ Did you get same error info?

Comment: Questions about operating systems, their utilities, networking and hardware, are off topic here. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please delete this and ask, instead, on https://askdifferent.com/

Answer (score 5):

What I did to change my locale configuration was the following:

In the root of your user on Mac you edit the file `.bash_rc` or `.zshrc`, depending on the shell you use.

`nano .bash_rc`
or
`nano .zshrc`

and inside the file you write the commands that have been suggested to you:

```
    export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
    export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

You save changes and exit the editor.

Then you run the command:

`source .bash_rc`
or
`source .zshrc`

then you check that the changes have been made with the following command:

`date`

That's all, Now You have the date and time in the correct format!